# How to prepare for HSK3?

Tags: hsk

I have passed HSK2 already. Now my new target is HSK3. How is it different from HSK2 from your experience? What should I pay attention to? What about HSK4?

Answer (score 1):

You can review the vocabulary differences here:

[HSK2](http://www.nciku.com/godianado/vocab?vocabID=163720#U47109c9cf2676) vs [HSK3](http://quizlet.com/6058630/hsk-3-vocabulary-flash-cards/)

[This article](http://www.chinaeducenter.com/en/hsk/hsklevel3.php) also describes what a HSK 3 level should be able to achieve.

Comment: Thanks but I know this kind of difference. I printed 7 sample pdfs of HSK3. What I interested in personal opinion of people who passed both HSK2 and HSK3. f.e. Timing issues(Was it enough time or not), Grammar difficulties(which grammar rules must be reviewed before passing just word list not enough)